# TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined in Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working on javascript application and have MVC model in the controllers there is a userController.js  file and in models, there is a user.js in the cleanup function file in the Models folder. why I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined this error

```
//User.js files code goes here 

let User = function (dataUser) {
  this.dataUser = dataUser
  this.errors = []
}
```

// In the cleanup function I checked the input type string and then avoid any bogus entries by using trim and lowercase properties but I am getting an error ie Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined this error

```
User.prototype.cleanUp = function () {
  if (typeof this.dataUser.username != "string") {
    this.dataUser.username = ""
  }
  if (typeof this.dataUser.email != "string") {
    this.dataUser.username = ""
  }
  if (typeof this.dataUser.password != "string") {
    this.dataUser.username = ""
  }
  this.dataUser = {
    username: this.dataUser.username.trim().toLowerCase(),
    email: this.dataUser.email.trim().toLowerCase(),
    password: this.dataUser.password
  }
}
User.prototype.login = function (callback) {
  this.cleanUp()
  usersCollection.findOne({ username: this.dataUser.username }, (err, attemptedUser) => {
    if (attemptedUser && attemptedUser.password == this.dataUser.password) {
      callback("Success")
    } else {
      callback("Invalid  username / password")
    }
  })
}
                    
// userController.js code 
exports.login = function (req, res) {
  let user = new User(req.body)
  user.login(function (result) {
    res.send(result)
  })
}
```

Comment: You are doing wrong check this condition `if (typeof this.dataUser.email != "string") {     this.dataUser.username = ""   }` you are checking for email field and assigning empty string in username field. same as check for password condition too wrong.

Comment: Thanks a tonne dear!!!! its a simple copy-paste mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

This means that the key that you are looking to trim inside `dataUser` is not present. So to fix it you would have to place an if check before you do the `trim()` operation. You can write something like this:

```
this.dataUser = {
    username: this?.dataUser?.username?.trim().toLowerCase(),
    email: this?.dataUser?.email?.trim().toLowerCase(),
    password: this?.dataUser?.password
  }
```

This is the shortest possible way to fix this.

Comment: Its fixed up and running